# Calling nested javascript functions

Tags: javascript

How do I call the function `Hey()` which is inside another function?
I tried doing function.function() but it seems not the right way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Reply() {
            createScene.Hey(); //not getting called
        }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var scene = null;

        var createScene = function () {

            function Hey() {
                console.log("OOPS");
            }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can't. It's local to that function.

Comment: But is it not a nested function? JS does not have any way to call the child function from its parent?

Comment: It's not a 'child function', it's a local function.

Comment: So I cannot make it global unless I declare it outside createScene()?

Comment: You could write `createScene` in such a way that it creates a global when it is called (which it currently isn't).

Comment: You should probably read up on objects and classes.

Comment: You could return Hey from createScene and use it or save it for use.

Comment: Go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: You probably should read on `closures`.

Comment: This is what is known as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Try asking more about what you're trying to _achieve_ than how you _think_ it should be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It's a local function. There's no way to access it. In fact, that's one of the (awkward) techniques people use to create private methods in JS.

You can return the local function, maybe define it on `window` or assign it to a global variable etc (to expose it externally); however the most idiomatic way would be to simply create a class:

```js
class Scene {
  constructor() {
    // create scene here
  }

  hey() {
    console.log('hey')
  }
}

const scene = new Scene()
scene.hey()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `createScene.Hey()`, then you have a few options, but none of them will look like what you have there.

One way: createScene as an object instead:

```
var createScene = {
   Hey: function() {
   }
};
```

If you want it to be a function as it is, and it have another function attached to it, I suppose it's possible, but not via nesting. You can do it like this:

```
var createScene = function () {};
createScene.Hey = function() {};
```